# Need Fix: Cannot open modal from button inside a Custom control inside Listview-DataTemplate-ViewCell

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, navigation, modal-dialog

I have a weird issue, but it maybe because I don't understand. I created 2 Custom controls. [Custom Control A] has a button named [LAUNCH] that launches a modal. [Custom Control B] has no buttons but has Custom Control A inside.

I made a page with [Custom Control B], but when I click [LAUNCH], while debugging it goes to the line of code that says await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ModalPage()) but after that, it doesn't launch the Modal.

I tried just adding [Customer Control A] and click [LAUNCH] and it was able to show the Modal.

Is there something I need to do to be able to open the Modal from Custom Control B?

EDIT: Upon further checking, I forgot to mention that [Custom Control B] is a control I bind for the item templates of a listview. I've tested again just loading one [Custom Control B] without a listview and it was able to open the Modal. However, when I put it back inside the listview as an item template, the issue persists. Do I need to do something for this to be able to run? Or is it impossible?

EDIT 2: Made a new sample project and isolated the case, it looks like it's really preventing the modal from Opening.

[Custom Control A]

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestXamarin.Controls.CustomControlA">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" HeightRequest="300">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <FlexLayout Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnOpen"
                    Text="Try Open Modal"
                    Clicked="BtnOpen_Clicked"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

[Custom Control A].cs

```cs
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomControlA : ContentView
    {
        public CustomControlA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void BtnOpen_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Modal());
        }
    }
```

[Custom Control B]

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TestXamarin.Controls"
             x:Class="TestXamarin.Controls.CustomControlB">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Frame BorderColor="Accent"
               HeightRequest="300"
               WidthRequest="300">
            <controls:CustomControlA
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></controls:CustomControlA>
        </Frame>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

[Custom Control B].cs

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomControlB : ContentView
    {
        public CustomControlB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

[Main Page]

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestXamarin"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TestXamarin.Controls"
             x:Class="TestXamarin.MainPage">
    <ListView x:Name="listSample"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <controls:CustomControlB/>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

[Main Page].cs

```cs
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();

            listSample.ItemsSource = list;
        }


    }
```

Comment: could you show your code ?

Comment: Hello Leo, I've added my code. Let me know if it helps. I'm still trying out some stuff with it.

Comment: I've isolated the case in a new project for less code, seems to be still happening.

Comment: I've given you another simple solution, and you can see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It looks like buttons would only work if they're from the context of the ListView item.

So I made a command binding property for Custom Control A and Custom Control B and made a command on the ListView Item's ViewModel to open the Modal. I was then able to open the modal through the command.

Answer (score 1):

you could also call push modal page like this(i think it should specify the Navigation stack):

in your **BtnOpen_Clicked** method :

```
private async void BtnOpen_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Modal());
   }
```

Comment: Hi Leo,

I debugged and I was able to reach the code here, however, as I continue and it tries to launch the modal, it fails. No error, the page just doesn't appear.

But I was able to resolve this already, see my answer below.

Thank you.